# Writing A JSON File in Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am creating an Ionic Application and I need to save data in a JSON file.

To create that file, I run:

> this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'test.json',
>   'hello,world,', {replace: true});

But the code above doesn't do anything. test.json doesn't get created!

What is the Issue?

***EDIT:*** Someone told me I must use cordova. Is that true? If so, what does he mean?

***EDIT:*** Is it because i can't file "this.file.dataDirectory"?

PS: I am using (ionic cordova run browser) to run the script. Would that cause problems.

Also, After using Melchia's example, I don't even get a console.log!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command to install cordova file plugin:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file
```

After installing a plugin’s package, add it to your app’s NgModule.

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';


...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    File
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then in your page.ts

```
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

constructor(private file: File) { }


this.file.writeFile(this.file.dataDirectory, 'test.json', 'hello,world,', {replace: true}).then(_ => console.log('Directory exists')).catch(err => console.log('Directory doesn\'t exist'));
```

Comment: I have done all that just not the ".then(_ => console.log('Directory exists')).catch(err => console.log('Directory doesn\'t exist'));" part. I will make the changes and then update you. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. I made the change and I don't get any console.log or does the json file get created. I don't know if this matters nut I am running with "ionic cordova run browser". @Melchia

Comment: but did you test this in your device?

Comment: Ofcourse it will not work in the browser because you're using cordova

Comment: You can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: I did.     'this.download("test", "testing.txt", ".txt")'      After taking the function you refered me to. Will this make a text file named testing.txt? @Melchia

Answer (score 0):

I think for ionic V4, you should use import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the original question, maybe you're trying to comment on the existing answer? It's better to put your comment under that answer, rather than as a whole new answer, or perhaps to suggest an edit to the existing answer with your new syntax, if you're certain it's correct.